# Jquery ui connections of dynamically made elements not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some elements like this:

```
$("#select_h").draggable({
  connectToSortable:".group",
  helper: "clone",
  revert:"invalid"
});
$("#datepick_h").draggable({
  connectToSortable:".group",
  helper: "clone",
  revert:"invalid"
});
$("#group").draggable({
  connectToSortable:".group, .fc",
  helper: "clone",
  revert:"invalid",
  stop: function() {
    updateConnections();
  });
```

So, they are dragging to Sortables like this:

```
$( ".group" ).sortable({
  connectWith:".group",
  receive: function(event,ui) {
    $(newItem).css("color","cyan"); 
  },
  beforeStop: function (event, ui) { 
    newItem = ui.item;
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

all works, but dragged groups don't recieves elements and working different from groups made on the first build of page.

Tried to update connections:

```
function updateConnections() {
   $("#select_h").draggable( "option", "connectToSortable", ".group" );
   $("#datepick_h").draggable( "option", "connectToSortable", ".group" );
   $("#group").draggable( "option", "connectToSortable", ".group, .fc" );
   $(".group").sortable( "option", "connectWith", ".group" );
}
```

after dragging a group element, but nothing changes.

That's the solution?

Comment: Can you show your working code?